# How to get the last id from inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the ID of my master table to be inserted to my transaction table. The insert is happening inside a loop.

Behavior:

- Insert master
- Get id
- Insert Transaction
- Insert Master
- Get id
- Insert Transaction

Controller:

```
 //Insert Master
 foreach($arr_master as $res_master){

    /*$data['ID_REQUIREMENT_TRANS'] this is an auto-increment column. Inserted automatically*/

    $data['ID_REQUIREMENT']     = $res_master;
    $data['SENT_BY_DATE']       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                                                             
    $data['STATUS']             = 1;            

    $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);

        //Insert Trans
        foreach($arr_trans as $res_trans){


            $data_d['ID_REQUIREMENT_TRANS'] = $id; //Need to get the last inserted id of the master table               
            $data_d['RECEIVED_BY']              = $res_trans; 
            $data_d['RECEIVED_BY_DATE']     = NULL; 
            $data_d['STATUS']                   = 1;            

            $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic_d($data_d);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
function ins_assign_pic($data){
    $q_ins_assign_pic   = $this->db->insert('pm_requirement_assign_pic',$data);
    return $q_ins_assign_pic;

    $id = $this->db->insert_id(); 
    return $id;      //How to send this to my controller
    return true;
}

function ins_assign_pic_d($data_d){
    $q_ins_assign_pic_d = $this->db->insert('pm_requirement_assign_pic_d',$data_d);

    return $q_ins_assign_pic_d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try controller

```
$id = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);
```

And model

```
function ins_assign_pic($data){
    $q_ins_assign_pic   = $this->db->insert('pm_requirement_assign_pic',$data);
    //return $q_ins_assign_pic;

    $id = $this->db->insert_id(); 
    return $id;      //How to send this to my controller
   // return true;
}
```

Comment: `$id = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);` gives me double data in the master. If I use `$id = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);`, only one data in master is inserted. why??

Comment: Maybe you wanna look into `foreach($arr_master as $res_master){` for that... @ashura91

Comment: if I use other value , ex: 1 as the ` $data_d['ID_REQUIREMENT_TRANS']`. The data insertion is perfect. I think it's not the foreach.

Comment: @ashura91 What i gave is standard method.. for further note if your `foreach` have 2 values then 2 rows will be inserted if 1 row then 1 row will be insert... :)

Comment: 1 question though why are you defining `$arr_trans` outside of parent `foreach`....

Comment: `arr_master and arr_trans` are just a char separated string like `1,2,3,4,5` or `A@B@C`

Comment: @ashura91 Well bro debug hard and get the results... This is all i can help you with..

Comment: SOLVED. ty for the clue

Answer (score 0):

Way 1

```
SELECT MAX( id ) FROM tableName;
```

Way 2

```
SELECT tableName.id FROM tableName ORDER BY tableName.id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Is `MAX(id)` always the last inserted id ?? even when there are deletion / change in the id?

Comment: On this case its better to use Way 2

Answer (score 0):

You are doing little wrong here.
once `return` call in function then it will not execute further.

**Model:**

```
function ins_assign_pic($data){

    $q_ins_assign_pic   = $this->db->insert('pm_requirement_assign_pic',$data);

    if($q_ins_assign_pic){
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        retun false;
    }

}
```

**Controller :**

```
 $newID = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);
```

Comment: `$newID = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic($data);` gives me double data in the master. If I use `$newID = $this->MAdmin->ins_assign_pic();`, only one data in master is inserted. why??

Comment: Show me your response.

Comment: what response??

Answer (score 0):

You could get the max id from the table:

```
select max(id) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_insert_id() is the Function you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but how send the variable to use in my controller

Comment: return $this->db->insert_id();  will return the ID. Then you can make it like: $myid = myfunction(); Then you can use the inserted ID in the var $myid.